# ASP.NET - cookieless=UseCookies - only session id in browser? No client cookies?

Tags: asp.net, security, cookieless

I'm working on asp.net (4.0) web site. I was trying to use form authentication (). Obviously trying to have some of pages secure. My understanding that best solution for security is to set cookieless="UseCookies" so it not going to write id to URL.

My question is what exactly happening when I use cookieless="UseCookies".

1. Is session created and some id stored in Browser(~memory which used later to pull info from IIS server side session "cookie") or it's actually spouse to create "regular" client side encrypted cookie?

(I'm obviously trying to avoid writing to URL and to client side cookies - not sure if all that could be avoided)

1. If it sets ID in Browser does all the browsers allow store session ID in it. If it's not allowed by Browser what is going to happened? Is there a way to pre check it?

So I guess as all of us I'm just trying to build proper secure application if anyone got any other suggestion it will be greatly appreciated.

Tanks a lot,

Comment: You should add more tags to your questions, otherwise people will have hard time finding it. Try asp.net or something.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow cookies so set cookieless="false" the sessionID will be stored in the cookie and it'll be accessible throughout the length of the session (which by default is 20 minutes.)

If you allow cookies and the user will have cookies disabled in the browser, sessionID will not be stored anywhere, and every times user creates a new request (by going to another page) he will get new sessionID, thus no data can be kept.

You can use cookieless="true" which will encrypt and append sessionID to the url, so that the user will be able to keep the session even though his cookies are enabled.

There is also a cookieless="AutoDetect" which will determine if the user has cookies disabled or enabled and based on that will either create a cookie with sessionID or throw it to the URL. The downside of this, is that each request to your page is resulting in 3 requests, one request determines if the user has cookies enabled, appends a query string with the result from first request, and third takes the user to appropriate URL.

There is also a setting that will turn cookieless off and on based on data about the browser. So if someone is browsing your page with 10 years old mobile phone it'll probably append cookies to URL as there is no option to allow cookies on that device.

I hope this helps. I personally would message the user to enable cookies and don't even worry about other cases but some people (like my boss, for example) doesn't like the idea and wants everyone supported.

Comment: Let me make sure if got you correclly. 1. To keep sesson id it could be in browser (or url if divice does not supports it) or in client cookie. So url request could be hijackt as well as cookie could be stolen and we do not have any better way to build it? I understand that problem only for life time of the session 2. If protection="All" in form in(web.config) is it correct that session and cookie encripted? 3. Can I check if divice suppurts cookie and going to write to url? Agine thanks for help.

Comment: 1. Yes but the sessionID is always encrypted in both URL and cookie. 3. I think ASP.NET has a list with devices and their cookie support values. I am not 100% sure how this works. I am sure you can google for that.

Comment: So what would you say is the best way to build it? (i can not use ssl as of right now) Just use cookie to store session id? and hope it not going to get stolen. Or some better way exists?

Comment: I'd say use cookieless="false" and if someone has cookies disabled just say "Please enable cookies to continue", and everyone else will have their sessionID in a cookie.

Comment: Hopefully last couple questions. Then you say cookie - are they saved on disk or browser/memory. Because I do not see any created in my cookies folder(only if check remember me in login control). I assume if they are in memory it's bit more safer than just a cookie file on hard drive.Also, if it's in memory will user setting affect "cookies save" process  since it's not going to hard drive? or all browser different?

Comment: The values for cookieless="UseCookies | UseUri | UseDeviceProfile | AutoDetect" from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx